# Someone is calling from my number, and its not me?

Tags: phone, spoofing

My number is being regularly spoofed by someone. Today, I got 100 + calls from people claiming I called them. I answered some of the calls they are all locals from my province. I asked my provider telus(Canada), they said there was no outgoing calls today from my account. So its not because my phone was hacked. How is this even possible?

**Questions:**

How is this possible for someone to use my number since numbers are assigned to a single sim card?

Are their software available now that's capable of doing this? (Call with anyone number?)

Whats the name of these software/providers so I can research this topic?

Whats their motive generally speaking? Because the calls were all missed calls when the spoofed called those people.

Comment: More generally, there's already a large number of questions about [phone number spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=phone+number+spoofing) on the site. You may want to go through that list, to see if any of them apply to your situation.

Comment: Also, I see you're pretty new to the Stack Exchange network, so you might not be aware, but please try to limit each question post to a single question which can be answered authoritatively. Question posts with multiple questions are likely to end up being closed as "too broad", and questions which cannot be authoritatively answered are likely to be closed as "primarily opinion-based".